# static final variables in a generic class causing unchecked & rawtype warnings

Tags: java, generics

Is it a design flaw to have a static final variable in a generic class? Consider the class below, all references to `Node.SOIL` give rise to warnings. What is a good way of going about solving this problem?

```
public class Node<E> {

    private static int nodeCounter = 0;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })  
    public static final Node SOIL = new Node(null, null); // <-- HERE
    public static void resetSOIL(){
        SOIL.children = null; // <-- HERE
    }

    private Node<E> parent;
    private Set<Node<E>> children;

    protected Set<Node<E>> isomorphs;
    private E data;
    private int id;

    public Node(Node<E> parent, E data){
        this.parent = parent;
        this.data = data;
        this.id = ++nodeCounter;

    }

    public boolean isRoot(){
        return (this.getParent() == SOIL);
    }

    // utility methods
    ....
}
```

Comment: Do you really need SOIL to be static? resetSOIL is going to have an impact on all your Node instances, is that the expected behaviour?

Comment: It's a design flaw to have global state (a mutable static).

Comment: @assylias well, the idea is to have a mother-of-all type node, which I believe is what `SOIL` is good for? `resetSOIL()` exists to avoid annoying problems when running unit tests (all nodes from the previous tests remain in `SOIL` otherwise)

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline even if it's finalized? hmm on a second thought, the fact that SOIL is final doesn't mean that it cannot be mutated, as a matter of fact it does mutate (gets children)...

Comment: @posdef Yeah, quite. Global state often sneaks under the radar by the initial static reference being `final` and then that points to something mutable.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline I see... Do you have a suggestion as to how to improve the design without compromising the functionality? (in other words, how can I keep a valid reference to SOIL without declaring it static final?)

Comment: @posdef I don't really know what it is. In general an instance variable in an object that needs it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined a type `Node<E>` which represents a node in a tree of E's. For example, `Node<Integer>` is a node in a tree of Integers,  and `Node<String>` is a node in a tree of Strings.

Now you want a variable `SOIL` that contains all the roots of these various trees of different types (hehe, *soil*, I get it now). Set aside the static field issue for now. What should the class of `SOIL` be? In other words, how do we declare and create the `SOIL` instance?

```
Node</*something1*/> SOIL = new Node</*something2*/>(null, null);
```

Since `SOIL` is going to have children that are `Node<Integer>` and `Node<String>` then it has to be something like `Node<?>` or `Node<Object>`. You can't instantiate an object using a wildcard type argument, so the best you can do is something like this:

```
Node<?> SOIL = new Node<Object>(null, null);
```

(If you use the Java 7 diamond construct `new Node<>(...)` it ends up using `Object` in this case anyway.)

The problem is, this still doesn't work. The way the `Node<E>` type is defined is as a **homogeneous** tree of E's. But one subtree of `SOIL` is a tree of Integers and another subtree is a tree of Strings, so `SOIL` wants to be a **heterogeneous** tree. Therefore, `SOIL` cannot be a `Node<E>` for any `E`.

At least, not in a type-safe fashion. You could write the code to do this, but you'd have to add some casts, and you'd get unchecked warnings. These warnings would tell you that this approach isn't working. For example, consider some code that takes a `Node<E>` and operates on all of its siblings (that is, the other children of its parent). Some code that took a `Node<Integer>` could call this and end up with a bunch of instances of `Node<String>` and start throwing `ClassCastExceptions`.

You might consider making `SOIL` a `Set<Node<?>>` and not making it be the parent of all the roots. You could make it a static field somewhere, but make it private.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a design flaw to have a static final variable. The warning appears because you are declaring an instance of a generic type without providing a type parameter:

```
public static final Node SOIL = new Node(null, null); // <-- HERE
```

when the compiler is expecting something like:

```
public static final Node<SomeType> SOIL = new Node<SomeType>(null, null);
```

Comment: THe problem is that in the `Node<E>` class I don't know what `E` will be at runtime, which is why I bothered with generics in the first place. So I can't really declare SOIL with `SomeType`. Or have I misunderstood your suggestion?

Comment: @posdef: So what do you want to do with this `Node` instance if it cannot take any type parameter?

Comment: as I mentioned above in a comment, the idea is to have a mother-of-all type node, regardless of the actual data type that's carried in the hierarchy of nodes.

Comment: @posdef: I guess you could use `Node<Object>` to avoid the warning. Don't know it this is what you need though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to avoid suppressWarnings and it works well:

```
private static final Node<Object> SOIL = new Node<Object>(null, null);
```

To answer to your other question:

```
Is it a design flaw to have a static final variable in a generic class?
```

No itsnt, it is even a good common practice to use it as default for null variables of type Node, aka the NULL object in Effective Java Programming